# How to get file name in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, databricks

This will load all data from several files into a comprehensive data frame.

```py
df = sqlContext.read.format(
  'com.databricks.spark.csv'
).options(
  header='false',
  schema = customSchema
).load(fullPath)
```

`fullPath` is a concatenation of a few different strings.  Anyway, I thought I could incorporate the file name into the `sqlContext` function, but it didn't work. This gives me an error.

```py
df = sqlContext.read.format(
  'com.databricks.spark.csv'
).options(
  header='false',
  schema = customSchema,
  withColumn(
    "filename",
    input_file_name()
  )
).load(fullPath)
```

How can I load everything from several data sets and the file name as well?

Here is the error message:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
  File "<command-540264511625083>", line 43
    df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', schema = customSchema, withColumn("filename", input_file_name()).load(fullPath)
                                                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the error you are getting?

Comment: whoopsy-daisy I already corrected this issue in my edit :). Thought this was just a typo really, sorry .. you are missing a closing bracket `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see how it works now.  The withColumn function goes at the end.  This is what worked for me.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', schema = customSchema).load(fullPath).withColumn("filename",input_file_name())
```

Also, you need to add the correct reference at the top.

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
```